# Windows Phone 7 Emulator Not able to connect to Windows Live ID

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm trying to connect to Windows Live ID using the Live SDK from this site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx

When I run this code in my emulator, I get the Live SignIn Button. When I click on it, it tries to connect to Windows Live, but always ends up with

"We're unable to complete your request
Windows Live ID is experiencing technical difficulties. Please try again later."

And this happens all the time - does it need some permission or sth like that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this happened because I gave a wrong ClientId in the XAML code for the signIn Button.

If you use a Sign In Button, you have to provide the ClientId property along with the ID you got.